# about pointer in c language in GCC,Linux environment

Tags: c, linux, pointers, gcc, dereference

Here in c code given below,i have declared one integer pointer but not initialized means it is wild pointer,so when i will try to dereference it it should give segmentation fault.But it is not given SAG.FAULT,why?

(in linux environment with gcc compiler)

```
/*not giving segmentation fault*/
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int *p  ;

 printf("%p\n",p);
 printf("%p\n",*p);

return  0;
}
```

and if i initialize that pointer with some value than it is giving me segmentation fault in code given below

```
/*it is giving segmentation fault*/
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int *p =12444 ;

 printf("%p\n",p);
 printf("%p\n",*p);

return  0;
}
```

Comment: You should know that a pointer, points to some memory location, and that number you try to assign to it is illegal, because you didn't allocate some memory for that pointer (*p).

Comment: Try this **gcc -Wextra -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wconversion --std=c11 -O0 -g program.c -o program** [this is what you need](http://ideone.com/5nPvkk)

Comment: By the way the content of *p you print it with **%d** and not with **%p** like when you try to print its address.

Comment: Since memory locations are whole numbers it is better to use unsigned int ...use %u instead of %p

Comment: @ch3rub7 Really? what if the numbers turns to **-25** ?

Comment: @Michi I'm not talking about *p which shows a value(it definitely must be %d as you said) but as p stores address of some other variable, it must always be a whole number... Simply *p is a value and p is address.. Therefore its apt to print *p with a %d and p with a %u.

Comment: i know that all things but my question is that if i do not initialize pointer means it will have some garbage address and when i execute  it every time i get different address but after dereferencing i am getting same data,why?

Answer (score 2):

```
int *p
```

declares a pointer to an integer. Dereferencing it is not giving you segfault as it is pointing to some unknown location.

```
int *p = 12444;
```

This statement is wrong. Pointer to an integer is used to hold the address of an integer. So you are basically misusing the functionality by assigning random number to pointer which is illegal.

For example,

The actual usage should be

```
int a;   // Declare a variable
int *p;  // Declare a pointer
p = &a   // Initialize p with the address of a
```

Comment: Short answer should be, that, that pointer should point to some memory location before you actually try to assign it to that number.